# What is the meaning/significance of explicit "extern" keyword in function declaration?

Tags: c, extern, function-declaration

Please explain why it uses `extern` in function declaration?

*main.c*

```
...
pthread_create(&displayThread, &attr, displayThrFxn, &displayEnv);
...
```

*display.h*

```
extern Void *displayThrFxn(Void *arg);
```

Why `extern`?

*display.c*

```
...
Void *displayThrFxn(Void *arg)
{
    // some code
}
...
```

Comment: @RalphWiggum Not really, this question is about C, not C++, and has nothing to do with the C++ linker (what `extern "C"` is used for in C++)

Comment: Whoops, must've picked the wrong result in the duplicate list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `extern` here is kind of redundant. By default, if nothing is specified, functions have external linkage.

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.2.3

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`. [...]